# how to add "/" to end of line if it does not exist with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to come up with a script to format forwards for apache, what I need to do is take a url, strip off the domain and then attach a "/" to the end of the line IF there is not one there already, now the script I have come up with is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/http:\/\/www.mydomain.co.uk//g' address > address1

sed -e 's/$/\//' address1 > address2
```

now this script will take off the "http://www.mydomain.co.uk" at the begining and add a "/" at the end, but some of the url's I have already have the "/" there. how can I get sed to only add the "/" if its not already there?

Answer (score 9):

Match a character other than a slash at the end of the line and replace with the match (`&`) plus a slash:

```
sed 's![^/]$!&/!'
```

To make things a little easier, I changed the delimiter from `/` to `!`, so that the slashes in the find/replace parts don't need to be escaped.

Comment: I would have done simply (no backreference): `sed -e 's#[^/]$#&/#'`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do:

```
$ echo 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk' | sed '/\/$/! s|$|/|'
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/

$ echo 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/' | sed '/\/$/! s|$|/|'
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/
```

Multiple commands can be combined as well:

```
$ echo 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/abc' | sed 's|http://www.mydomain.co.uk||g; /\/$/! s|$|/|'
/abc/
$ echo 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/abc/' | sed 's|http://www.mydomain.co.uk||g; /\/$/! s|$|/|'
/abc/
```

**Notes:**

- Might work for your cases, but `.` needs to be escaped to match a literal `.` for ex: `s|http://www\.mydomain\.co\.uk||g`
- `g` flag is needed only if there is more than one match in a line

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do this with multiple commands:

```
$ cat file
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/foo/
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bar

$ sed 's#http://www\.mydomain\.co\.uk\(.*[^/]\).*#\1/#' file
/foo/
/bar/
```

Note that `.` is a regexp metacharacter meaning "any character" so you need to escape it if you want it treated literally.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
abcd/
efgh

$ sed 's:/\?$:/:g' file
abcd/
efgh/
```